# UITableView delete button not appearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, editing

When I press the edit button I get the round delete icon to the left of the item.  When I press the delete icon in the cell it 'turns' but the delete button does not show up so my commitEditingStyle never gets called because I have no delete button to press.

Just for fun...I change the cell to Insert I get the plus icon...I press it and commitEditingStyle is called.

I do not understand why I am not getting the delete button.

I have a UIViewController that I am showing in a popover.  I am adding a UITableView to like so...

```
audioTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 303)];
audioTable.delegate = self;
audioTable.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:audioTable];
```

I am using a custom cell with two labels in it to display text.

Here is the custom cell initWithFrame...

```
primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25 ,8, 275, 25)];
primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25 ,28, 275, 25)];
secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

[self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];
[self.contentView addSubview:secondaryLabel];

[self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:primaryLabel];
[self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:secondaryLabel];
```

I have a delete button in a toolbar in the view controller that is hooked up to the edit call.  Here is what I am doing in the edit call which is getting called fine because I am getting the delete symbol in the cell...

```
if([self.audioTable isEditing]) {
    [button setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [self.audioTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
} else {
    [button setTitle:@"Done"];
    [super setEditing:YES animated:NO];
    [self.audioTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

I have implemented the following...

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //i don't think i need to implement this really
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //do delete stuff
    }
}
```

Like I said everything is working normally, button presses and all work...just no delete button.

Comment: Hm, strange. All this seems fine. Are you sure you don't add some random views which hide the delete button.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  No other views are being added at all...Just a custom cell with 2 labels.  Could a custom cell have anything to do with this?

Comment: The two labels are the textLabel and detailTextLabel or they're added using addSubview?

Comment: they are added using [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel]; in the initWithFrame call on the custom cell view...then layoutSubviews is called on the Custom cell view.

Comment: @digthewheels that's the problem, they're hiding the delete button.

Comment: How should I add them so the delete button is shown?  What would be the best way?

Comment: @digthewells: are you adding a custom delete button ?

Comment: I am not adding a custom delete button.  The delete button just won't show for some reason.  I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to work around it by using a different mechanism.  I did a test and when I used a `UITableViewController` it worked fine.  When I added a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`, implementing the same thing as the `UITableViewController` does, it does not work.  I do not know what I missed, but using the `UIViewController` as opposed to the `UITableViewController` caused the delete button to not appear.

Comment: I meet the same problem with you and I solved it as you said.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I cannot use a `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. The problem was that my tableView's frame was not being properly resized inside the popover. In reality the delete button was being displayed but it was outside the bounds of the popover so it couldn't be seen.

I fixed this by ensuring the `tableView` resizes appropriately. For me this meant setting the tableView's `autoresizingMask` like this:

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

The reason others were able to fix this by switching to a `UITableViewController` is because its `tableView` is properly resized.

Answer (score 2):

I know you fixed it using a `UITableViewController` but I couldn't in my case.

Looking around I just found the answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1751270?start=0&tstart=0), you need more plumbing to get the job done. Fortunately its pretty easy. Add this to the `UIViewController` containing a reference to your `UITableView`

```
// objc
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

// swift
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Looking back I believe this would have solved the problem.  I was able to use the UITableViewController so I did that and moved on.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I had already tried this, but was doing it out of order (calling self.tableView.setEditing before calling super) and was running into issues.  Swapping the order of those calls fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the labels using addSubview: to the cell's content view, and as they're added as last, they hide the other parts of the cell. Push them into the background by calling:

```
[cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:label];
```

Comment: I have added this to the initWithFrame call on the custom cell after the addsubview...didn't work.  I tried layoutSubviews on the custom cell and didn't work.  I also tried cellForRowAtIndexPath and my customizeCell call that I use to put the data from core data into the cell and none of them made a difference...what you are saying makes sense...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @digthewells sorry but I don't have more idea. Try rewriting your code using a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the style of the delete button

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip...this very well could solve the problem!  I have not tested this out yet, but when I have another need to do this I will definitely give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: this did not work for me. still looking for solution =(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the `UIViewController.editButtonItem` in the button bar (which automatically changes the editing property of the view controller). As I was using a UIViewController with a UITableView, I needed to delegate the setEditing to the tableview, e.g.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom tableview not the TVController. You must set atleast three delegates

Swift 4.2

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .insert {

    } else if editingStyle == .delete {

    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And most important is to add 'tableView.isEditing = true' in the viewDidload :)